# list of lists with pairs that do not have a match in the original set

Tags: python, combinations, list-comprehension

I have a set of tuples in a form of a list:

```
[(1, 2), (3, 4), (5, 6), (7, 8)]
```

Not necessary in such an order, it can be as well:

```
[(1, 4), (2, 6), (3, 5), (7, 8)]
```

These lists have two properties:

- if sorted and flattened  they become a range from 1 to `n` (like `[1, 2, 3,..n]`)
- `n` is even
- `n` is larger than 2
- all values are unique (no value is repeated).

so, let's say I have:

```
a = [(1, 2), (3, 4), (5, 6), (7, 8)]
```

**What is the way to create list of tuples `b` out of `a` such that no original tuples would be in it?**

so for example

```
b = [(1, 8), (3, 7), (2, 6), (4, 5)]
```

is ok but

```
b = [(1, 2), (3, 7), (5, 6), (4, 8)]
```

is not ok, because it contains `(1, 2)` and `(5, 6)` presented in `a`

PS: *(The title is messy, but I don't know how to explain better (will be happy to edit).*

Comment: Naive approach: Flatten, rotate-by-one, rechunk.

Comment: Hello. Do you want a method to create just a single list b? or do you want a method to create all such lists? or, finally, just an amount m of them (if they exist)?

Comment: @Lorenzo: just one list that satisfies these conditions would be enough

Comment: Then @schwobaseggl answer is sufficient.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Building on my naive approach comment:

```
a = [(1, 2), (3, 4), (5, 6), (7, 8)]
b = [(x[1], y[0]) for x, y in zip(a, a[1:]+a[:1])]
# [(2, 3), (4, 5), (6, 7), (8, 1)]
```

This pairs elements from adjacent pairs and thus guarantees no pair is in the original list

Comment: This should be fine, except that it seems as though the examples he's presented have tuples in increasing order. Not sure if that matters at all.

Comment: I believe this makes it.

Comment: @RushabhMehta If it matters, you can always sort the result.

Comment: This is cute. Reminds of the famous diagonal slash proof.

Answer (score 1):

Here's an idea using `collections.deque` and `itertools`. The idea is to flatten, rotate, then split into pairs. Assumes you don't require any sorting in the result.

```
a = [(1, 2), (3, 4), (5, 6), (7, 8)]

from itertools import chain, islice
from collections import deque

dq = deque(chain.from_iterable(a))
dq.rotate()

res = list(zip(islice(dq, 0, None, 2), islice(dq, 1, None, 2)))

print(res)

[(8, 1), (2, 3), (4, 5), (6, 7)]
```

Comment: For all its verbosity, this is probably the more consequent and performant implementation of my approach. `res = [(dq.popleft(), dq.popleft()) for _ in range(len(dq)/2)]` is one byte shorter and saves you one util method ;)

Comment: @schwobaseggl, Thanks for the appreciation :). Yes, I know it's verbose, but very "lazy" too!

Comment: @schwobaseggl Alternatively even shorter without any utils: `res = [(a[i-1][1],a[i][0]) for i in range(len(a))]`

Comment: @NickA But it would be exactly as long as my answer ;) if I had cheated on the spaces after the commas, too. One longer, actually

Comment: @schwobaseggl You win this time ;)

Answer (score 0):

Well, here's one. I might be misunderstanding your original question though.

```
l = [(1, 2), (3, 4), (5, 6), (7, 8)]
m = max(itertools.chain(*l)) # Largest number in input
nos = range(1, m) # List of numbers we can pick from.
all_tuples = set(itertools.combinations(nos, 2)) # All possible tuples
not_in_original = all_tuples - set(l)
```

Here's a test

```
[x in l for x in not_in_original]
[False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False]
```

Comment: I feel like there's a step missing here, or something. `not_in_original` contains, among other things, `(1,2)`, which _is_ in the original.

Comment: @Kevin Stupid me. Forgot to subtract those from `all_tuples`. Fixed.

Comment: Ok, looking a bit better :-) but `not_in_original` still doesn't quite match the desired output as I'm interpreting it. I would expect it to be a tuple, not a set; and to have a length of 4, not 18.

Comment: Well, we can just convert it back into a list.

Comment: If you're saying "well then you can just do `result = tuple(not_in_original)[:4]` and satisfy both the type and length requirements", I think the result _also_ needs to satisfy all of the properties in the bullet points in the question. On my machine, `tuple(not_in_original)[:4]` gives me `((4, 7), (1, 3), (5, 6), (1, 6))`, which violates the "no value is repeated" property.

Comment: Good point. We'll need another filter to remove items that violate the original constraints.